# AdMob for Android AIR : app banner is empty

Tags: android, air, admob

I keep publishing this but the ads are not appearing on my Android app. I am looking for interstitial and bottom center (nothing else). Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong with the code? I can publish it onto device without any errors, the paths to the swc and ane files are accurate. But... when I try to test it on the device, no ads show! Usually you will see the Google "filler" banners.

```
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.*;
 import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.events.*;
 import com.model.Model;

 if (! Model.isAdCreated) {
 if (! AdMob.isSupported) {
    log("AdMob is not supported on this platform.");
    return;
 }
 AdMob.init("ca-app-pub-0689398111452070/6711053641");
 log("AdMob v"+AdMob.VERSION+" Initialized!");

 //AdMob.enableTestDeviceIDs(AdMob.getCurrentTestDeviceIDs());

 AdMob.addEventListener(AdMobErrorEvent.FAILED_TO_RECEIVE_AD,onFailedReceiveAd);
 AdMob.addEventListener(AdMobEvent.RECEIVED_AD,onReceiveAd);
 AdMob.addEventListener(AdMobEvent.SCREEN_PRESENTED,onScreenPresented);
 AdMob.addEventListener(AdMobEvent.SCREEN_DISMISSED,onScreenDismissed);
 AdMob.addEventListener(AdMobEvent.LEAVE_APPLICATION,onLeaveApplication);
 Model.isAdCreated=true;
 }
 function showSmartBanner():void {
 log("->display smart banner.");
 AdMob.showAd(AdMobAdType.SMART_BANNER, AdMobAlignment.CENTER, AdMobAlignment.BOTTOM);
 log("Requested show smart banner.");
 }
 function showAdTopLeft():void {
 log("->display ad top left...");
 AdMob.showAd(AdMobAdType.BANNER, AdMobAlignment.LEFT, AdMobAlignment.TOP);
 log("Requested show ad top left.");
 }
 function showAdTopRight():void {
 log("->display ad top right...");
 AdMob.showAd(AdMobAdType.BANNER, AdMobAlignment.RIGHT, AdMobAlignment.TOP);
 log("Requested show ad top right.");
 }
 function showAdBottomCenter():void {
 log("->display ad bottom center...");
 AdMob.showAd(AdMobAdType.BANNER, AdMobAlignment.CENTER, AdMobAlignment.BOTTOM);
 log("Requested show ad bottom center.");
 }
 function showInterstitialAd():void {
 log("Loading interstitial..// pass false for preoading only");
 AdMob.loadInterstitial("ca-app-pub-0689398111452070/8187786843", true);
 log("Waiting for interstitial to auto-show.");
 }
 function refreshIt():void {
 log("Refreshing banner ad.");
 AdMob.refreshAd();
 }
 function removeAd():void {
 AdMob.destroyAd();
 log("->ad destroyed");
 }

 function onFailedReceiveAd(e:AdMobErrorEvent):void {
 log("ERROR receiving ad, reason: '"+e.text+"'");
 }

 function onReceiveAd(e:AdMobEvent):void {
 log("Received ad:"+e.isInterstitial+":"+e.dimensions);
 showSmartBanner();
 }

 function onScreenPresented(e:AdMobEvent):void {
 log("Screen Presented.");
 }

 function onScreenDismissed(e:AdMobEvent):void {
 log("Screen Dismissed.");
 }

 function onLeaveApplication(e:AdMobEvent):void {
 log("Leave Application.");
 }

 function log(msg:String):void {
 trace("[AdMobExample] "+msg);
 //txt.appendText(msg+"\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the onReceiveAd handler might be getting called upon interstitial display. The banner that is then shown could be closing the interstitial.